# Explicit conversion from int to byte in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an int to byte.

```
int i = 128;
byte b = (byte) i;
```

I know the range of byte if -128 to 127 and the rule of storing an integer to a byte is :

byte_value = int_vale % byte_Range; (I found that in Complete reference Java)

When I apply this to int 128 it should be like this:

byte_value = 128%256 = 128;

But, it actually is : -128

I am not able to understand the actual logic behind this.
Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is simple, Java numbers are always signed in two's complement.

Now a byte has 8 bits and 128 is `10000000`. When you do

```
int i = 128
```

you end up with:

```
i == 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000
```

When you cast it to a byte you the 24 most significative are truncated, so you end up with

```
b == 10000000
```

but a Java `byte` is signed, and 128 can't be represented, since it overflows and wraps around. So what happens is that the value ends up as `128 - 256 = -128` (that's because of two's complement).

Answer (score 5):

Casting to `byte` doesn't mean `int_value % byte_range`.  It means that only the last 8 significant bits are kept in the `byte` value.  At first that seems to mean the same thing, but `byte`s are signed.

The `int` value `128` is the following bits:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000
```

When the last 8 bits are kept, this is the result:

```
10000000
```

Now, the most significant bit in the `byte` is interpreted as -128, not +128 as it was in the `int`.

The value `128` overflows a `byte`, and the result is negative because of that most significant bit being set.

Comment: +1, and JLS citation is [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3): "A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T." That (and not Complete Reference to Java or whatever) is the ultimate definition of how the operation works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following method:

```
byteValue()
```

This returns the value of this Integer as a byte.

You will need to either import Java.lang or type it out as:

```
Java.lang.Integer.byteValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bytes are treated as [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) values in Java; like you pointed out, the range of a byte is [-128,127]. Adding 1 to 127 flips the sign bit, which means that 127 + 1 = -128.