# Is a cast necessary when assigning an int literal to a byte variable?

Tags: java

I read a book with a line:

```
byte rounds = 12, fighters = (byte) 2;
```

It states

> The byte primitive has a four-byte signed integer as its valid
>   literal. If an explicit cast is not performed, the integer is
>   implicitly cast to one byte.

According to Oracle doc, isn't a byte should be one byte in nature?

Comment: The java language specification sometimes seems to be very narrow minded/low-level. `byte b = 300;` would give an error, but in general an int constant may be downsized to a byte. And 300 is an int. That is meant.

Comment: At least related if not a dupetarget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886332/why-can-i-assign-an-integer-literal-to-a-short-type-variable-but-not-to-a-short

Comment: The book you read is wrong.  Perhaps, avoid books by the same author in the future.  Also, consider reporting the error in the text to the publisher so they can get it fixed in the next release of the book (if it has one).

Comment: That’s a misleading statement, at best. The literal `12` is *always* an `int` literal. You may only use an `int` literal when *assigning* (includes initializing) a `byte` variable, if the literal value fits into the `byte` value set. But you can not, for example, pass the literal `12` as a argument to a method expecting a `byte` parameter. There is no implicit cast from `int` to `byte`. Note that this applies to integer constants in general, e.g. you can also write `byte b = 'a';` because it fits into the byte value set, or `char c = 97;`…

Answer (score 2):

Java provides special literals for initializing primitive data types, for example

```
int a = 1234;
double b = 12.34;
float c = 56.78f;
char d = 'x';
```

The documentation says that there is no special literal for `byte` type. Instead, primitive type `byte` shares its literal with `int`. When a signed 32-bit `int` literal "fits" into a single byte, Java will perform an implicit conversion; otherwise, it will produce a compile-time error.

Comment: Does it mean [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) ?

Comment: @RexT 5.1.3 talks about conversions that you force by manually adding a cast. If you write `byte x = (byte)12345` that would be a narrowing conversion, which Java allows. When you write `byte x = 12345` that would be an attempt of an implicit narrowing conversion, which Java disallows, because `12345` does not fit in a `byte`. When you write `byte x = 45` there is an implicit narrowing conversion that Java allows, because `45` fits in a `byte`.

Comment: I am still unsure. According to the statement "If an explicit cast is not performed, the integer is implicitly cast to one byte.". So the `2` in `fighters = (byte) 2;` is 4-byte, and `12` in `byte rounds = 12` is 1-byte ?

Comment: @Rex T: the *variables* `rounds` and `fighters` have the declared type `byte`, nothing else. The values `2` and `12` are always `int` values.

Comment: @RexT To a Java compiler both `2` and `12` are `int` literals representing four-byte integers with top three bytes set to zero. In the absence of the cast the conversion is implicit, so four-byte value must represent a number that fits in a signed byte. When you add a cast, the conversion is explicit, so there is no restriction on the value of the 32-bit integer constant.

Comment: Reference about why `byte x = (byte)12345` equals to `57 `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351898/explicit-conversion-from-int-to-byte-in-java

Comment: it is Narrowing Primitive Conversion - as explained in [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-200)

Answer (score 1):

> If an explicit cast is not performed, the integer is implicitly cast to one byte.

If a book says that, it is incorrect.  Or at least, it is not telling the whole story.

<sup>(Technically speaking, these are conversions not casts.  A cast involves the Java `(<type>)` syntax.)</sup>

The whole story about *implicit* narrowing *conversions* is as follows:

- They only apply in an *assignment context*; see [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).
- They only apply when the value being cast is a (compile time) constant expression; see [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).
- They only apply when the value type is  `byte`, `char`, `short` or `int`
- They only apply when the target type is  `byte`, `char` or `short`, or the corresponding wrapper types (`Byte`, `Character` and `Short`).
- They only apply when the value will "fit" in the target type without truncation.

For example:

```
   byte b = -1;      // OK
   Byte b1 = -1;     // OK
   byte b2 = 255     // Error: value is not in range of 'byte'
   byte b3 = 1 + 1;  // OK
   byte b4 = b + 1;  // Error: not a constant expression

   public void test (byte b) {...}

   test(byte(12));   // OK: explicit narrowing conversion
   test(12);         // Error: not an assignment context.
```

In summary, this conversion is only allowed if the compiler can determine that it can *never* lead to any loss of information.

Comment: *"A cast involved the Java `(<type>)` syntax.)"* This is also not quite the whole story; there are implicit casts when using generic code, for example if you have a `List<String>` and you write `String s = theList.get(0);` there is an implicit cast to type `String`; if the element happens not to be a `String` (possible e.g. if you started with a raw `List`) then it fails with a `ClassCastException`. This is, of course, not the same kind of implicit conversion, I'm just making an observation that not all casts are explicit in the source code.

Comment: Umm ... the "implicit type cast" you are talking about here (which is a real thing) is actually a Narrowing Reference  Conversion, I think; see JLS 5.1.6, paragraph 2.  The phrase "implicit type cast" is not used in the JLS.   My point is that the book text quoted is playing fast and loose with the terminology.  (But this could be that the quote has been taken out of context.  We don't actually know which book the OP was reading ... so we can't check.)

Comment: The JLS doesn't call it a cast, but given that it fails with a `ClassCastException`, I think it is reasonable to call it a cast; and the bytecode for `theList.get(0)` is the same bytecode as generated for `(String) theList.get(0)` so there is a real, technical sense in which it is an implicit cast even though the JLS doesn't call it one. Another example is `byteVar += intVar;`, which the JLS says is "equivalent to" `byteVar = (byte)(byteVar + intVar);`, and they generate the same bytecode, although the JLS calls this a "conversion" rather than a "cast".

Comment: That said, I agree that the quoted sentence from the OP's book is not strictly correct.

Comment: 1) I disagree with your inference based on the class name.  A simpler explanation is that they thought it would be a bad idea to *retrospectively* add another class called `ValueConversionException` or something.  2)  In the assignment expression case, the text states that what is actually performed is a Value Set Conversion See 15.26.2.  It doesn't say "type cast" at that point.  The equivalence that is mentioned at the start of the section is (to my mind) intended as a reader-friendly hand-wavy summary rather than being normative.

Comment: (I don't have time to do it now, but it would be interesting to understand the history of "conversion" versus "implicit type cast" in older versions of the JLS.)

Comment: If there was an intentional decision to use `ClassCastException` for a conversion which should not be called a cast, then I would expect to see that mentioned in the documentation for the `ClassCastException` class - which says *"Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance"*. Again, just an inference, but I think it's a reasonable inference.

Answer (score 0):

A byte is one byte. But the literal 12 is of type integer, which is 4 bytes. What the sentence says is that when you write `byte rounds = 12`, an implicit cast exists to transform 12, the integer, into a byte.

Comment: Surely there's a dupetarget for this?